# Learning XNA/Xbox Development

Tags: xna, xbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I go about learning XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22423/how-should-i-go-about-learning-xna)

so I would like to get into Xbox game development (indie games.) The problem is I cant find ANY documentation or place to get started online. I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction (tutorials or documentation.) I was also hoping someone could direct me to some kind of online course? (Paid or free.) I appreciate your time, thanks.